# Should I use the article in the following sentence?

Tags: articles

Should I use the article in the following sentence?

"Demand for apple is increasing"

or

"The demand for the apple is increasing"

or

"The demand for apples is increasing"

Comment: Hi Yun-Lung Lee. I can't really say "Welcome to ELU" because this is the fourth question you've asked here, and none of them have yet received a single upvote. That's because *you're asking on the wrong site* - this level of question from a non-native speaker belongs on 
[English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The third.  Except that if you're speaking of a particular type of apple then the second would be correct:  "Haralson apples are suddenly 'in' again.  The demand for the apple is increasing."  And the first might apply if you're talking about apple as a food component:  "Sauce, juice, or concentrate, the demand for apple is increasing."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The 3rd is by far the most frequent**, and is correct.

The 1st can be heard too, but very rarely:

> The National Nurseryman - Volume 19 - Page 401 1911
>
> It will make digging much lighter than usual. Trade conditions are
>   satisfactory, and indications are that our fall deliveries both in
>   fruits and ornamentals will be far above the average. The **demand for
>   apple and peach** in all grades has increased ..

The 2nd is incorrect.